# Passing title of annotation to new view

Tags: objective-c, annotations

In my app, I have a mapView that drops a pin with a UILongPressGestureRecognizer. When the screen is pressed, the coordinate is geocoded and a pin is dropped, and the address is set as the title. There will be multiple pins on the screen, and the annotation view has a callout accessory that pushes another controller, called the PinViewController onto the stack. The PinViewController has a label, which I want to show the title of the pin.

Here is the code for dropping the pin:

```
-(void)press:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [recognizer locationInView:worldView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate = [worldView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:worldView];

    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithCoordinate:touchMapCoordinate
                                                    altitude:CLLocationDistanceMax
                                          horizontalAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                                            verticalAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                                                   timestamp:[NSDate date]];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location
               completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                   NSLog(@"reverseGeocoder:completionHandler: called");
                   if (error) {
                       NSLog(@"Geocoder failed with error: %@", error);
                   } else {
                       CLPlacemark *place = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                       geocodedAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@, %@ %@", [place subThoroughfare], [place thoroughfare], [place locality], [place administrativeArea]];

                       if (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan == [recognizer state]) {
                           addressPin = [[MapPoint alloc]initWithAddress:geocodedAddress coordinate:touchMapCoordinate
                                                                   title:geocodedAddress];
                           [worldView addAnnotation:addressPin];
                       }
                   }
               }];
}
```

And here is the code where the PinViewController is pushed to the stack:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    PinViewController *pinViewController = [[PinViewController alloc]init];
    [[self navigationController]pushViewController:pinViewController animated:YES];
    pinViewController.label.text = addressPin.title;
}
```

The trouble I am having is that the label is only showing the last address to be geocoded. So when I drop the a pin and press the callout accessory button, the correct address is pushed to the PinViewController. But if I press the callout accessory button of another annotation, the address of the last pin dropped is pushed to the PinViewController. So I need to find a way so that when I press the callout accessory button of a annotation view, the title of the annotation is passed to the PinViewController. I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using `addressPin` which is always going to be the last pin that was geocoded. You need to use the `annotationView` to access the annotation that was pressed.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    PinViewController *pinViewController = [[PinViewController alloc]init];
    [[self navigationController]pushViewController:pinViewController animated:YES];
    pinViewController.label.text = view.annotation.title;
}
```